# Convert list items into list dict values in ppytohn

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I've a lists of lat and long as:

```
lat = [42.60834522099568,
 43.06020110865567,
 42.360866652845225,
 43.83584752940632,
 42.53519122926045,
 42.108529046055956,
 42.74949717537388,
 42.11758854120139,
 44.16156595083669,
 41.95492006730041]

long  = [-79.02331314523865,
 -76.23570772800629,
 -75.25151045575511,
 -73.77168233997514,
 -74.85122527994935,
 -75.85720543124457,
 -78.83460087609063,
 -75.99188925992554,
 -73.58430725175869,
 -75.30436786195708]
```

I want to convert lat and long lists into list of dicts.

Expected output:

```
[{'lat':  42.60834522099568, 'lon': -79.02331314523865}, 
 {'lat': 43.06020110865567,  'lon': -76.23570772800629 }, 
 {'lat':  42.360866652845225, 'lon': -75.25151045575511}]
```

Comment: You are looking for [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lat = [42.60834522099568,
 43.06020110865567,
 42.360866652845225,
 43.83584752940632,
 42.53519122926045,
 42.108529046055956,
 42.74949717537388,
 42.11758854120139,
 44.16156595083669,
 41.95492006730041]

long_ = [-79.02331314523865,
 -76.23570772800629,
 -75.25151045575511,
 -73.77168233997514,
 -74.85122527994935,
 -75.85720543124457,
 -78.83460087609063,
 -75.99188925992554,
 -73.58430725175869,
 -75.30436786195708]

long_lat = []
for n in range(len(lat)):
    long_lat_dict = {}
    data_lat = lat[n]
    data_long = long_[n]
    long_lat_dict['lat'] = data_lat
    long_lat_dict['long'] = data_long
    long_lat.append(long_lat_dict)

print(long_lat)
```

Output:

```
[{'lat': 42.60834522099568, 'long': -79.02331314523865},  
 {'lat': 43.06020110865567, 'long': -76.23570772800629},
 {'lat': 42.360866652845225, 'long': -75.25151045575511}, 
{'lat': 43.83584752940632, 'long': -73.77168233997514}, 
{'lat': 42.53519122926045, 'long': -74.85122527994935}, 
{'lat': 42.108529046055956, 'long': -75.85720543124457}, 
{'lat': 42.74949717537388, 'long': -78.83460087609063}, 
{'lat': 42.11758854120139, 'long': -75.99188925992554}, 
{'lat': 44.16156595083669, 'long': -73.58430725175869}, 
{'lat': 41.95492006730041, 'long': -75.30436786195708}].
```